# Convert sql query to codeiginiter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tb_slots` 
WHERE `service_name`='Paragliding' 
and repetition > (
                    SELECT count(*) 
                    FROM `user_booking` 
                    WHERE date='2019-11-17' 
                    and `time-session`=`tb_slots`.`id` 
                    and `pay_status`='Success'
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as converting a SQL query to CodeIgniter.

If you wish to have the query working in CodeIgniter's query builder, it's should be easy following the documentation here:
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would help you

```
$this->db->select('*');     
    $this->db->where('service_name','Paragliding');
    $this->db->where('`repetition` > (SELECT count(*) FROM user_booking WHERE date="2019-11-17" and time-session=tb_slots.id and pay_status="Success"'));
    $this->db->get('tb_slots');
```

thanks

Comment: Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

SELECT * FROM `tb_slots` WHERE `service_name` = 'Paragliding' AND `repetition` > (SELECT count(*) FROM user_booking WHERE date="2019-12-12" and `time-session` = `tb_slots`.`id` and `pay_status` = "Success"

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/paragliding/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: there is missing paranthsis please have a look again.    
$this->db->select('*');     
    $this->db->where('service_name','Paragliding');
    $this->db->where('`repetition` > (SELECT count(*) FROM user_booking WHERE date="2019-11-17" and time-session=tb_slots.id and pay_status="Success"'));
    $this->db->get('tb_slots');